# Remove other section names from the headline

Tags: beamer, presentations

I am looking for a way to remove, for a given section, the other section names from the headline; actually I have long section names, so some of which are not appearing in the headline.
In other words, in the headline of the second slide, I want to replace 'Introduction' with 'Part 1'. Also, in this case, I have to remove 'Part 1' from the headline of the first slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
  ......
\end{frame}
\section{Part 1}
\begin{frame}{Part 1}
   ......
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
%    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
     \vskip2pt\quad\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsection \vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\addtoheadtemplate{\pgfuseshading{beamer@headfade}\vskip-1.25cm}{}

\makeatother

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\large}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=structure.fg!50!white}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
  ......
\end{frame}

\section{Part 1}
\begin{frame}{Part 1}
   ......
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you please tell me how can I change the font size (of the text in the headline)? Also, how to change the opacity of this text. Thank you!

Comment: @din Please see my edit. Instead of the opacity, you can change the colour.